# Multiple tabs issue during the downloading of the Excel sheet from Jasper server

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

all I'm new to Jasper reports. I've  used Rest client API to download the Excel report from the Jasper server it is working well.Actually I need to get only summary[for both national and international calls],national[only national calls]&International[only international] tabs but it is generating etc tabs like sheet 4, sheet 5.....sheet 14.When I download the report from server GUI I'm getting the only 3 tabs which is fine.But with rest client api only i'm facing issue.So,please help me to fix the issue.

Regards,
Naveen.

Comment: Please post code

Comment: Thanks @gmsOulman. Code means my Rest client or jrxml?

Comment: Not sure - I haven't worked with Jasper or Rest client API, this came up for me because of the Excel tag. You're describing the problem in words but really the community needs to see _how_ you are using the Rest client API and requesting the Excel reports. Use screenshots if they're more appropriate, and make sure the code is not too verbose - check out the [minimal, complete, verifiable example help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code is big to attach here.Can we add excel parameters like pagination and break to our java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague  just increased the pageHeight attribute value in jrxml value.So the issue cleared.Now the tabs are not splitting , I'm getting the desired output.